# .eps and .pdf image in one document

Tags: graphics, pdf, conversion, eps, svg

I want to include both pdf and eps image in one latex document.
I created a svg image in Inkscape. The .pdf version of the same is exactly like the .svg image. but the .eps version some part of image is missing.
All the other images in my document are .eps except for this 2-3 files which i mentioned above. I tried many software to convert the pdf to eps but the result is always same. Those parts are still missing.

Is it possible to incorporate .eps and .pdf in one document ?
How?
or what other solution can you give me for my problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Comment: Just don't include the figure file extension like `\includegraphics{figure}` and include [epstopdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg) `\usepackage{epstopdf}` in preamble to have on the fly `.eps` to `.pdf` conversion. On TeXLive 2012 is automatic without any package inclusion. Also [epstopdf perl script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) `epstopdf figure.eps` at command line window/terminal will convert `.eps` to `.pdf`

Comment: You are generating a pdf of the whole document so somewhere there has to be a conversion from eps to pdf (either before, during or after inclusion into the document) If the pdf conversions are going wrong there is probably an error in the EPS.

Comment: Voting to close this question as a duplicate, even though the other question is newer – the other one is more canonical already.

Answer (score 1):

From Adobe site:

> The moral to this story is that PDF can be used as a replacement file format for EPS, and that PDF can be used as a delivery format for sending complete publications to press. (http://www.adobe.com/print/features/psvspdf/)

So, if you can create the pdf version of yours eps from the original source will better you do it and only work with the pdf format. If it isn't possible, you will need to use `epstopdf` (as said in the comments of your questions).